# Remove item from Array, with item that doesn't provide equality

Tags: .net, arrays, f#

How would I remove an item from an array, provided that it does not have equality?

For example, for an item with equality, I could do the following:

```
Array.filter (fun x -> x <> itemToRemove) array
```

Unfortunately, that does not work since in my case, I have a tuple in which the third item is a curried function (to which I provide the last argument later), and this does not have equality.

EDIT:

Here is the exact example I am having problems with:

```
let arrayWithoutReq = Array.filter (fun (req:(string * Port<'a> * ('a -> bool) option * int * DateTime)) -> req <> fullfilableReq) (originalFifoRequests.toArray())
```

Comment: Can you show MCVE?

Comment: That entirely depends on what your rules for equality are. Are you talking about identity (exactly the same object) or value comparison (two different objects but are semantically representing the same value)

Comment: @FoggyFinder Added the code that I am having problems with

Comment: @RuneFS It would be in my case exactly the same object

Comment: great, now show me that you have and what you want to get in the end.

Comment: While this *can* be done, as seen in the answer, that doesn't mean it *should* be done here. Seriously, look at that tuple type! And it needs reference equality? Just define a type for it! There's a `[<ReferenceEquality>]` attribute that works on records and unions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are talking about identity comparison, use the build in reference comparison

```
let arrayWithoutReq = 
    originalFifoRequests
    |> Seq.filter (fun req -> 
           Object.ReferenceEquals(req, fullfilableReq) |> not)
    |> Seq.toArry
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to work :) In my case I didn't need the seq to array part, but Object.ReferenceEquals works!

Comment: @Choub890 cool that it works. The Seq.ToArray was only to be on par with the original code and if you don't need an array you should of course not create one as I've done above